Expo dev-client with offline development?
I would like to be able to develop offline mode (disable the WiFi/Network connection), while keeping hot reload with Metro?  If I do this, the bundle won't load and i am not connected to metro.
I have tried suggestions per docs like expo start --offline but the network requests are still attempted. I think because I am not using Expo Go, I cannot use expo start.
If I turn off my WiFi on my laptop, then the bundle won't re-load.  I have tried connecting to my laptop by using the --device flag.  No difference.
Do I just need to hardcode the NetInfo mode to "offline" in my provider?
